# Using Math.random flexibly

Tags: javascript, string, random, operators

I would like to create a 4 letter long string, RANDOMLY containing any of the letters from the string: "ROYGBV".

What I've done is this:

```
function generateSolution(){
    var colors = "ROYGBV";
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        var loc = Math.ceil( Math.random()*colors.length );
        str += colors.charAt(loc);
    }

    return str;
}
```

But this doesn't seem right, why is this?

also, this is from the exercise's solution:

```
str += colors.charAt((Math.random() * 6) | 0);
```

I used Math.ceil in my solution to prevent randoming floats like 4.333123 and so on. How does this solution work, without rounding the randomed numbers?

Also, what does the `|` operator mean? and how does the randomization in the second solution actually work?

Comment: @frrlod: Why are you changing your question so much once you've received answers?

Comment: I wanted to put an emphasis on the second part of the question, but you're right. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` is the [bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29). Since bitwise operations in JavaScript only work with 32-bit integers, that's a shorthand way of rounding a a number towards 0. In your case it's equivalent to this:

```
colors.charAt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)));
```

The number needs to be floored instead of rounded up, as you are currently doing with `ceil`, or you will miss the first element of the array (which is at index 0).

Here's the full details of the conversion to integer from [the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.10):

> The production A : A @ B, where @ is one of the bitwise operators in the productions above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *A*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *B*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lnum* be ToInt32(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rnum* be ToInt32(*rval*).
> 7. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result is a signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: `|` is not a shorthand for flooring, it's shorthand for round towards zero, with NaN and Infinity -> 0.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this fully answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

You want `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.ceil()`. Javascript arrays are zero-based, so you want values between 0 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function generateSolution() {
    var colors = "ROYGBV",
        str = "",
        l = colors.length,
        i = 0;

    while (i < 4) {
        var loc = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
        str += colors.charAt(loc);

        i += 1;
    }

    return str;
}

console.log(generateSolution());
```

On [jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/R3AAR/)

You need Math.floor, the | is just a bitwise method of performing a 32bit floor