# display specific object values in an array instead of individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have used an ajax call to retrieve data from Googles places api and I have used a for/in loop to begin to pull the information. the information that I am looking for logs to the console, but I cannot get it to display in an array how I would like it to.

Right now I am getting a list of names when I request names which is a parameter in the JSON object. Is there a way to get it into an array so the I can randomly select one of the values from the array?

at this point the way it is returning my data, when I run a script to pull a random string, it pulls a random letter out of the last value to be found when searching through my JSON object.

Here is my code. Not sure if I explained myself clearly but it's the best that I could word what I am looking to do. Thanks.

```
// **GLOBAL VARIABLES** //

// Chosen Restaurant display area
var display = document.getElementById('chosenVenue');
// Grab button
var button = document.getElementById('selectVenue');
// Sample Array that gets queried
var venueData = ["McDonalds", "Burger King", "Wendys"];



// Grab JSON data from Google
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'hungr.php', // Send query through proxy (JSONP is disabled for Google maps)
  data: { requrl: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7484,-73.9857&radius=800&sensor=false&keyword=restaurants,food&key=AIzaSyBkCkXIHFjvqcqrRytSqD7T_RyFMNkR6bA&callback=?"}, // URL to query WITH parameters
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET", // or POST if you want => update php in that case
  success: function (data) {
     // Traverse the array using for/in loop using i as var
     for (var i in data.results) {
         var results = data.results[i];
        var nameResults = results.name;
            console.log(nameResults);
        var typesResults = results.types;
            console.log(typesResults);
        var vicinityResults = results.vicinity;
            console.log(vicinityResults);

     };      


      // On button click, randomly display item from selected array
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        display.style.display = 'block';
        //display.innerHTML = nameResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameResults.length)];
        display.innerHTML = nameResults.toString() + "<br />"  + vicinityResults.toString();
      });



      console.log('It is working');

  },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log('It is not working');
}
});
    });
```

Comment: If possible , can post returned `data` object ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 the data that is returned in the console just lists the values so if i enter to console.log nameResults in my loop, it lists all of the values with the 'name' parameter in the console, but not in an array, just listing them as individual strings.

Comment: For clarity , referring to `data` object (literal) returned at `$.ajax()` `success` _before_ entering `for` loop.  E.g., `{results:[123, 456]}`

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I am getting a list of names when I request names which is a parameter in the JSON object. Is there a way to get it into an array so the I can randomly select one of the values from the array?

Use the `push` method and a non-local variable:

```
this.nameResults = this.nameResults ? this.nameResults.push(results.name) : [];
```

then reference that with the `Math.random` method:

```
this.randName = function(){ return this.nameResults[Math.random() * this.nameResults.length | 0] };
```

**References**

- [Using Math.random flexibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086213/1113772)
- [JavaScript: fast floor of numeric values using the tilde operator](http://blog.boyet.com/blog/javascriptlessons/javascript-fast-floor-of-numeric-values-using-the-tilde-operator/)